# Two integers with the same sinus

Tags: trigonometry, integers

Question is in the title. Are there two integers with the same sinus/cosinus?

i.e. $sin(\alpha)=sin(\beta)$ s.t. $\alpha,\beta \in N$

Comment: Surely you mean to say two *distinct positive* integers, otherwise every pair $(\alpha,\beta)$ where $\alpha=\beta$ satisfies your question, and positive in order to avoid talking about how $\cos(\alpha)=\cos(-\alpha)$ for all $\alpha$.  As for the question of if $\sin(n)=\sin(m)$ for some pair  $(n,m)$ where $n$ and $m$ are distinct positive integers, I believe I read somewhere that the answer is no but I'm having difficulty remembering the specific theorem name and finding a citation.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:  You can consider one of the so-called Sum-to-product identities

$$\sin m - \sin n = 2 \sin\left(\frac{m-n}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{m+n}{2}\right)$$

If $\sin m = \sin n$ the left-hand side is $0$.  What do you know about the zeros of $\sin$ and $\cos$?